# Possible mailR/rJava Filepath Issue?

Tags: java, r, email, rjava, sendmailr

In the past, I have used the mailR package with no issues on both Mac and Windows. Ever since the last R/RStudio update, mailR and rJava will no longer work. I can install both packages just fine. But, I cannot load them with the library() command. When I try, I get the following errors:

```
> library(mailR)
>Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘mailR’: .onLoad failed in 
loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
error: unable to load shared object 
'/Users/rotendd/Library/R/3.4/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
dlopen(/Users/rotendd/Library/R/3.4/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library 
not loaded: @rpath/libjvm.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/rotendd/Library/R/3.4/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/libjvm.dylib: mach-o, but 
wrong architecture
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Libraries/libclient.dyl
ib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

and

```
> library(rJava)
>Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
error: unable to load shared object 
'/Users/rotendd/Library/R/3.4/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
dlopen(/Users/rotendd/Library/R/3.4/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library 
not loaded: @rpath/libjvm.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/rotendd/Library/R/3.4/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/libjvm.dylib: mach-o, but 
wrong architecture
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Libraries/libclient.dyl
ib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

From what I have found just Googling around, it seems that I need to manually change a file path in one of the functions. I think I can find my way around the Java folders to get what I need but I'm not sure how to manually change a file path in a package like this.

I think I have all the pieces to fix this problem, I just need a little guidance on orchestrating my solution. Thanks!

Comment: There are numerous possible sources of the issue. Take a look here: http://www.owsiak.org/r-3-4-rjava-macos-and-even-more-mess/ and here http://www.owsiak.org/r-java-rjava-and-macos-adventures/ where I have posted my solution to make R happy with Java on macOS